# Migrating from Rich Text Column to Plain Text Column with Powershell

Tags: powershell, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I have a SharePoint list with a few rich text columns. I am recreating the list in a new site (for a number of reasons such as column names, etc) and am changing all rich text columns to just plain text. I am going to use powershell to copy list items from one list to another. However, when I copy the source rich text column to the target plain text column, all of the HTML markup comes across as well (and as expected). Is there a way in the powershell script strip off the html and just bring over the "text".

Current target column value with script:

> -div- monthly report that is autogenerated and emailed -/div-

---- Note I replaced the `<>` characters on the div with `-` so the div appears in the text.

Wanted target column value with script:

> monthly report that is autogenerated and emailed

Answer (score 1):

You can mix this in your powershell script to strip off the html:

`$string = <your rich text column>`

`$string -replace '<[^>]+>',''`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but was looking for a similar thing and found the use of [GetFieldValueAsText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.getfieldvalueastext.aspx) method:

```
$sourceField = $sourceItem.Fields['SourceFieldName'] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiLineText]
$targetItem['DestinationFieldName'] = $sourceField.GetFieldValueAsText($sourceItem['SourceFieldName'])
```